# Animation ends abruptly

Tags: css, animation, hover

if I have the animation applied on hover then if I move the mouse out of the link the animation terminates abruptly. Is there some way to let if finish?

```
a:hover{
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  animation: test .5s infinite;
}
```

Comment: `animation: none;` or  `animation-play-state: paused;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that finishing the animation after hovering away can't be done with pure css. But you could add `mouseenter` function with jQuery like so:

```
$("a").mouseenter(function(){
   $(this).animate({
      <your animation>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
a:hover{
animation-name:your_animation_name;/*any name of your animation*/
animation-duration:1s;/*animation playing duration given by seconds*/
animation-timing-function:ease-in;/*play mehtods eg:-ease in , ease-in-out*/
animation-fill-mode:forwards;/*animation stop at to{} code. No come back style*/
animation-delay:1s;/*animation should start after... given by seconds*/
}

@keyframes your_animation_name{
from{}/*Where the animation begging*/
to{display:block;/*if you want add more codes insert here*/}/*final animation style*/
```